# Jquery UIDialog not working on ssl page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0

My code

```
  $('a[rel*=sidufbbox]').live('click',function() {
                          uiDialog({
                    url         : $(this).attr('href'),
                    data            : null,
                    type            : 'GET',
                    title            :$(this).attr('title')
                        },false,{modal: true,show: 'fade', hide: 'fade', title: $(this).attr('title'),   
                         close:function(){ 

                }, position:['middle',150], width: 750});
        return false;


    });
```

my link

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Privacy Policy',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','div'=>false,'help','admin'=>false),array("rel"=>"sidufbbox","title"=>"Privacy Policy"));?>
```

initially It was working when page url was just http, now i have made that page url as https ? may be this causing the issue, plz help me fix this issue ??

Comment: WHat do you mean by "not working"? What error do you get? Are you getting a response at all?

Comment: @DevlshOne: No errors just when i click on help button nothing is happening..!!

Comment: Are you sure that you load jQuery over https or a protocol relative URL (without protocol prefix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('a[rel*="sidufbbox"]')
    .on('click',function() {
        uiDialog({
            url : $(this).attr('href'),
            data : null,
            type : 'GET',
            title : $(this).attr('title')
        },
        false,
        {
         modal: true,
         show: 'fade',
         hide: 'fade',
         title: $(this).attr('title'),   
         close:function(){ 
         },
         position:['middle',150], width: 750});
         return false;
    });
```

Using the `F12` key, you should be able to put your browser into Web Dev mode and it should give you the details about what is happening. There are several items within the UIDialog options that look invalid to me. First of all, though, change your `.live` to    `.on`.

Regarding the `302 Error` :

**Resolving 302 errors - general**

> The 302 response from the Web server should always include an alternative URL to which redirection should occur. If it does, a Web
>   browser will immediately retry the alternative URL. So you never
>   actually see a 302 error in a Web browser, unless perhaps you have a
>   corrupt redirection chain e.g. URL A redirects to URL B which in turn
>   redirects back to URL A. If your client is not a Web browser, it
>   should behave in the same way as a Web browser i.e. immediately retry
>   the alternative URL.
>   If the Web server does not return an alternative URL with the 302 response, then either the Web server sofware itself is defective or
>   the Webmaster has not set up the URL redirection correctly.

Comment: after adding your code its giving me error as TypeError: $("a[rel*=sidufbbox]").on is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

.on('click',function() {

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @ DevishOne : jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Comment: Check that your quote marks are the same as mine in the selector. `$('a[rel*="sidufbbox"]')`

Comment: ya i checked it, its fine, now its giving me error: 302 Moved Temporarily in console

Comment: That's a good thing. No syntax errors. This could be a result of the move to SSL. You changed ports, correct?

Comment: Yes Boss "DevlshOne" You r right.. it fixed..!! thanks a lot..!! I accepted ur answer & upvoted..!!